# IIS 10 Windows Server 2019 - 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied when accessing ASP.NET MVC site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-10

- Fresh install of Windows Server 2019 and IIS 10

[image]

- Web Deployed an ASP.NET MVC 5 application to the website
- Anonymous user identity is set to "Application Pool Identity"

[image]

- Site level also has anonymous authentication enabled

[image]

- The `IIS AppPool\ApplicationPoolName` has the following effective permissions for the web root which sits under a root folder:

[image]

And yet when I access the website I receive a 403:

[image]

If I place a static file such as index.html in the web root then the contents of the file are served up as expected. So this seems related to MVC.

What have I missed here?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Am still struggling with this, 3days later

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem because I'd forgotten to enable `Application Development` features on the web server:

[image]

I had all the NTFS permissions correct but enabling the `ASP.NET 4.7` role was what I was missing.

Might not be the case for other runtime versions but this helped for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could re-check your folder to make sure your application pool identity has the perission to access that folder.

Details, you could refer to below steps:

1.Right click the folder which you hosted the application and select property.

2.Select the Security tab

3.Click the Edit button and then Add button

4.Click the Locations button and make sure that you select your computer.

5.Enter `IIS AppPool\ (eg: IIS AppPool\smartcrypt)` in the Enter the object names to select: text box.

6.Click the Check Names button and click OK.

7.Check Modify under the Allow column, and click OK, and OK.

Comment: hi @brando - I have done that and my effective permissions second last bullet point shows that read permissions are available?

Comment: Normally, we just need read permission to access file. That is enough. I suggest you could check the parent folder to make sure if there is other permission to deny the application pool identity to access the web sites.